# Visual Studio: Various Service/DLL Reference Errors in Project

Tags: c#, .net, version-control, reference

When trying to build a solution I've recently downloaded from source control (TFS in this case), I'm having all sorts of issues which other developers are not.

Sometimes, the project will build. Other times, it will not.

In general, I'm unable to make any source code changes, because as soon as I do, all the web & service references in the project appear to be broken. Re-adding the references does not fix the issue.

The service reference errors will appear as **"The type or namespace could not be found.."**, while at other times I will randomly get **"Could not load file or assembly.."**.

What is going on here? It doesn't appear to be project configuration related.

Comment: Are the missing DLLs compiled as part of the solution, or are they external/third party/Microsoft DLLs?

Comment: They were local DLLs - the problem manifested itself differently when running VS as Administrator/checking ProcMon, which led me to the ultimate root cause.. (posted below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the overarching problem was **Impersonation**. The impersonation account was trying to access many local files during the *build*, which was surprising to me.

You can check if impersonation is used in a project/site by checking the web.config (that is used in your development mode - if you use web.config transformations check your Debug/Release configuration) for:

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="XXXX" password="XXXX"/>
```

If impersonation is enabled, the **impersonation account** will need various access on your local machine.

In my case, the impersonation account needed full control to the following locations:

```
C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Documents\IISExpress\
DRIVE:\SourceControlProjectLocation\
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\VERSION
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\VERSION
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\VERSION\Temporary ASP.NET Files
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\VERSION\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

This was a real pain because because inheritance was broken **by default** in many of these locations by Windows itself.